# Notation in riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading a lecture on Riemannian geometry in which it is written that, for a differentiable manifold $M$ and a differentiable curve $v \, : \, I \, \longrightarrow \, M$ defined on an interval $I$, we have (by definition) :

$$D_{t}v \cdot \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) = v'(t)$$

I do not really understand what $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is the (canonical) basis vector of $T_t(I)$ the tangent space to the interval $I$ at the point $t$. The differential of a differentiable map $f \colon M \to N$ at $x \in M$ is a linear map $T_x(M) \to T_{f(x)}(N)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! As to be sure, if I want to prove that $\lbrace \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} \rbrace$ is the (canonical) basis of $T_{t}(I)$, can I put it like this : let $t \in I$, consider a differentiable curve $\gamma \, : \, (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \, \rightarrow \, I$ such that $\gamma(0)=t$ and a differentiable function $f \, : \, I \, \rightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$. Then, $\frac{\mathrm{d}(f \circ \gamma)}{\mathrm{dt}} \big\vert_{t=0} = \gamma'(0) f'(t) = \left( \gamma'(0)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} \right) f$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks ! Now I understand the expression $D_{t}v \cdot \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} \right)$